# Why was my reasonable comment deleted?

Tags: discussion, moderation

In the Gerardo Furtado answer to [Why does it hurt the next day after doing significant exercise?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/61020/why-does-it-hurt-the-next-day-after-doing-significant-exercise), I had a comment asking about whether the mechanism described had sound scientific basis. This comment was deleted, but the issue is the answer contains information addressing my comment. Moreover, the comment had several upvotes yesterday and is actually referred to in the answer with a broken link. Now the answer reads reads '*... [comment] now deleted*, next to that broken link.

Why was this comment deleted?  Is there something wrong with asking questions like this?  The author felt it compelled to address it in the answer.  I'm confused.  Is it against the rules here to ask questions about unproven hypotheses?

Comment: @AliceD The answer actually references the comment with a link to the deleted comment (which doesn't work).  And then says (now deleted) next to the broken link.  This seems like a lot of goofiness for nothing and isn't typical across other SE sites.

Comment: fyi - I undeleted your comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the comment has been noted and included in an answer, the comment seems redundant.

I always look if the comments are addressed in the question and/or the answers. If not, the comment may be important to keep as it adds something. If it's contained in the questions/answer, it's redundant.

I remove my own redundant comments all the time, upvoted or not. It's important to keep **questions and answers clean of clutter**. Personally, I don't put too much weight on comments and I think they are quite dynamic. I don't think it's an issue to remove them.

If the answer refers to a now removed comment - you, or the answerer can simply edit it into the answer proper. I think it's best to keep answers stand-alone, barred references to other questions and answers or outside links, of course.

But **in the end, comments should not be deleted when they are useful**. In your specific case I still recommend to edit your valuable information into the answer proper. Nonetheless, whatever you decide to do with your comment, I've un-deleted your comment. It shouldn't have been deleted.

Comment: I took at a look at the section of the answer which essentially is a response to my now deleted comment.  Unfortunately I lack the expertise to edit it appropriately without guessing about certain things.

Comment: Then we might just leave it like this, right?

Comment: Works for me.  Thanks.